# Is it possible to remove subscription box from Jetpack stats page?

Tags: plugins, plugin-jetpack, statistics

Is it possible to remove following box from Jetpack's stats page as I'm using Feedburner?

[image: Jetpack]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way might be to hide it using CSS. If there's a class or id unique to the container, add this to your theme's functions.php:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_admin_css_ha');

function custom_admin_css_ha() {
  echo '<style>
    #unique-id-or.unique-class-goes-here {
      display: none;
    } 
  </style>';
}
```